# Windows list (alt+tab) is not centered after disconnecting from external monitor

Tags: nvidia, monitor

I'm using a laptop and connecting it to an external monitor. After disconnecting from the external monitor, the list of windows (pressing and holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) is not centered. It is located in a place as if the external monitor is still connected (bottom right instead of center)

Has anyone else experienced this? How can I fix it? If it helps, I have a macbook pro 6,2 and the nvidia driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that I need to explicitly disable the external monitor (via Display Settings) before unplugging it. Otherwise, I get problems similar to yours.

Comment: What do you mean by "via Display Settings"? Monitors? "NVIDIA X Server Settings"?

Comment: @kilaka: My bad. I meant System > Preferences > Monitors, which the indicator icon calls "Display settings."

Comment: Tried again and it didn't work. Also, I'm not next to the external monitor right now. Is there a way to solve this without the external monitor?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to either log out and back in or memorize the necessary keystrokes ahead of time so you can control the monitor settings without being able to see the window. Alternatively, if you can find a way to move the window without having to see it, you can drag the Monitors window to where you can see it. The best thing, though, is just to remember to disable the monitor before you unplug it.